# Cannot escape quotes within a function

Tags: javascript

How can I escape these quotes?

I tried it like this. However, I cannot use double quotes, due to the effect that the `querySelector` is covered with double quotes `"`.

```
document.querySelector('[onclick=\'tabbed(\\'tabsrc-cnt2\\')\']')
```

Comment: *"I cannot use double quotes, due to the effect that the querySelector is covered with double quotes "."* I have no clue why that means you can not use them....

Answer (score 4):

You can pass a template literal into `querySelector` instead. As the template literal quote is `, both `"` and `'` can be used without needing to be escaped.

```js
console.log(
  document.querySelector(`[onclick="tabbed('tabsrc-cnt2')"]`)
);
```

```html
<button onclick="tabbed('tabsrc-cnt2')">button</button>
```

An easier to read option would be to select an element whose attribute *contains* `tabsrc-cnt2`:

```js
console.log(
  document.querySelector(`[onclick*="tabsrc-cnt2"]`)
);
```

```html
<button onclick="tabbed('tabsrc-cnt2')">button</button>
```

That said, if this is your own site, it would be better to avoid inline handlers entirely, [they have too many problems](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59539045) (including ugly escaping issues like this one) to be worth using nowadays.

Answer (score 2):

You can put the param in a data attribute and search for it that way.

```js
document.querySelector('[data-param="tabsrc-cnt2"]')

function tabbed(val){
  console.log(val)
}
```

```html
<div onclick='tabbed("tabsrc-cnt2")' data-param='tabsrc-cnt2'>Click Me</div>
```